# A problem to show that a certain field extension is not normal

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field, normal-extension

> **Problem:** Let $\alpha$ be a real number such that $\alpha^4=5$. Then show that $\mathbb Q(\alpha +i\alpha) $ over $\mathbb Q$ is not a normal extension.(where $i^2=1$)

**My approach:** I could show that the minimal polynomial of $(\alpha+i\alpha)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $x^4+20$ and in the splitting field it splits as $$x^4+20=(x-(\alpha+i\alpha))(x+(\alpha+i\alpha))(x-(\alpha-i\alpha))(x+(\alpha-i\alpha))$$$$=(x-(\alpha+i\alpha))(x+(\alpha+i\alpha))(x^2+2i\alpha^2)$$

As $(\alpha+i\alpha)\in \mathbb Q(\alpha+i\alpha)$ we have $-(\alpha+i\alpha)\in \mathbb Q(\alpha+i\alpha)$.

If I can show that $(x^2+2i\alpha^2)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\alpha+i\alpha)$ then I am done, that is $(\alpha-i\alpha)\not\in\mathbb Q(\alpha+i\alpha)$ which is equivalent to showing $i\not\in Q(\alpha+i\alpha)$ $\left( \because \frac{(\alpha+i\alpha)}{(\alpha-i\alpha)}=-i\right)$

But I could not figure that out. I am stuck here. I don't know if I have to use Galois' Correspondence here. Help me out. Thanks in advance!

Other approaches are welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i \in \mathbb Q(\alpha + i\alpha)$, then $1 + i \in \mathbb Q(\alpha + i\alpha)$, and hence $\alpha = \frac{\alpha + i \alpha}{1 + i} \in \mathbb Q(\alpha + i\alpha)$ too.

So $\mathbb Q(\alpha + i \alpha) = \mathbb Q(\alpha, i)$.

However, $$[\mathbb Q(\alpha, i) : \mathbb Q] = [\mathbb Q(\alpha, i) : \mathbb Q(\alpha)] \times [\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q] = 2 \times 4 = 8,$$
while
$$ [\mathbb Q(\alpha + i \alpha) : \mathbb Q] = {\rm deg}(X^4 + 20) = 4,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why is $[\mathbb Q(\alpha,i):\mathbb Q(\alpha)]=2$? Why is $x^2+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$?

Comment: $\alpha$ is real, so every element in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is real. Hence $i \notin \mathbb Q(\alpha)$. Hence $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$.

Comment: Will the same thing work if I had $\alpha$ not necessarily real ?That is if I considered $\alpha $ in some extension of $\mathbb Q$ such that $\alpha^4=5$.

Comment: I may sound dumb here but all I meant is that if it is possible to ask the same problem with the condition that $\alpha$ is not necessarily real.

Comment: Suppose that $\alpha^4 = 5$, with $\alpha$ not necessarily real. Then $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, i)  : \mathbb Q(\alpha)] $ is either $2$ or $1$. In the latter case, $i \in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$, so $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is an extension of $\mathbb Q(i)$, and $[\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q(i)] = 2$. That means that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q(i)$ is quadratic. But the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q(i)$ divides $X^4 - 5$, and there is no quadratic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(i)$ that divides $X^4 - 5$.

Comment: @Noobmathematician: the key is that if $\alpha^4 =5$ then $\mathbb {Q} (\alpha) $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb {Q} [x] /(x^4-5)$. And there are four such fields like $\mathbb {Q} (\alpha) $ (corresponding to each root of $x^4-5$). So if any one of these fields has a solution to $x^2+1$ then by isomorphism every field has this solution. Now use the power of $\mathbb {R} $ to conclude that one of these fields (which is subset of $\mathbb {R} $) does not have a root of $x^2+1$ so none of them have this root.

Comment: @Noobmathematician: Algebraically this is just proving that the field $\mathbb {Q} [x] /(x^4-5)$ has no solution to $x^2+1$ but instead we embed this into $\mathbb {C} $ and use features of $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C} $ to get such conclusions without any effort.

Comment: Thanks @ParamanandSingh for coming back to this old post and commenting .